# UML diagram shapes missing on Visio 2013

Tags: uml, visio, office-2013

I have installed Visio 2013 Standard and I'm trying to create an UML diagram.

I choose the "UML class" template but when it opens, the Shapes panel is empty. As recomended, I go to "More Shapes" menu, but cannot find anything related to UML.

Have anyone had this problem and got a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 35):

Software & Database is usually not in the Standard edition of Visio, only the Pro version.

Try looking here for some templates that will work in standard edition

- [UML 2.0 Diagrams and Shape Downloads for Microsoft Visio](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UML20DiagramsAndShapeDownloadsForMicrosoftVisio.aspx) which points actually to [www.softwarestencils.com](http://www.softwarestencils.com/uml/index.html)

Comment: Do you know if this has any compatibility issues with users that have the Pro version? Say, if I create a diagram with those shapes, and it's opened later using Visio Pro for editing? Am I right in thinking they're different or custom shapes than the ones Visio Pro offers?

Comment: You can also use this website http://www.softwarestencils.com/uml/#Visio2013 to download and manually install the UML 2.5 stencils and templates

Comment: Visio 2013 Pro doesn't contain UML MODEL DIAGRAM

Comment: This is buggy behaviour from Microsoft: they should either provide the template (with the shapes!) or not at all. As per @undefinedvariable question above, what happens if create a series of UML diagrams in Pro - can standard open it and/or manipulate it?

Comment: This is a bug, you have all these templates to choose from which are currently broken in the Standard Edition.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem with Visio 2016. I have the standard license. I think it is very strange that you can select a "UML Sequence" template when you search for it but it then opens a blank canvas without shapes. So you don't see anything and can't select the shapes under the "More Shapes" window on the side.

So I searched the shapes in the installation directory of Visio. I found in the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\Visio Content\1033` a couple of Sequence diagram templates (ie: BASIC_UMLSEQUENCE_M.VSTX). They are using the stencil `USEQME_M.vssx`. I found that out by right clicking the shapes in the left window and select "Save as". I saved them in "My Documents" under "My Shapes" just like custom shapes. I can than use them in any new document that I want.

Note the capital `M` or `U` in the name of the template or stencil for `US Units` or `Metric Units`. I'm from the Netherlands so I'm using the `M` version.

A not really friendly way to get the shapes. But it works.

Comment: In my installation I found them under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Visio Content\1033

Comment: This depends of course on which version you are using. I think you are using Visio 2013?

Comment: This was useful. I faced similar issue with visio 2016 as well.

Answer (score 16):

Microsoft is moving away from software and database diagramming using Visio and instead transitioning into Visual Studio.   See the "Modeling" Projects.  Component Diagrams, Sequence Diagrams, Use Cases, Layer Diagrams are all part of the modeling project.   While I am experimenting with it (but question its viability), you can generate code from the models creating in the code generation sense.

See also this post [Pet Shop Models](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2010/05/13/visual-studio-2010-how-to-maintain-control-of-your-code-using-layer-diagrams-custom-msbuild-tasks-and-work-item-integration.aspx) as well as the MSDN documentation: [Modeling the Architectural](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490886.aspx)

Here's what I have available in vs2013 ultimate
[image: Pet Shop Project]

Comment: But now it was removed from visual studio 2017

Comment: [Removed from VS 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/10/14/uml-designers-have-been-removed-layer-designer-now-supports-live-architectural-analysis/) here is the article.

Answer (score 10):

Microsoft Visio 2013 Standard Edition does not provide UML shapes, you have to upgrade to Microsoft Visio 2013 Professional.

[Visio 2013 Professional](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/visio-professional-2013-business-and-diagram-software-FX103791824.aspx)

Comment: I have Visio 2013 Pro and it doesn't contain UML MODEL DIAGRAM

Answer (score 7):

CTRL+N-- to open a new document.

Right Edge find "MORE SHAPES" then "SOFTWARES AND DATABASES" and finaly "SOFTWARES". All UML DIAGRAMS are available here.

Comment: "Softwares and Databases" option is not available. Is there anything I can do to make it appear?

Comment: U can search for it online and get it...Just use the search tool box and search for UML daigrams

Comment: Software & Database is usually not in the Standard edition of Visio, only the Pro version.

Comment: It's interesting that Vision allows creating a class diagram, but provides no stensils..

Answer (score 5):

Please check this KB article : **http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2259709** 
This issue occurs because Visio 2013 uses new UML and database modeling templates that are not used by Visio 2010 or by earlier versions of Visio.
And it applies to both :

"Microsoft Visio Professional 2013" and "Microsoft Visio Standard 2013"

So upgrading to Pro might not help as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't find Stencils you can locate them in your install location. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Visio Content\1033  for UML Sequcen Stencies you can open

Answer (score 3):

If you don't see stencils creating new document with a template you may open the template directly.
In my case they are located at 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Visio Content\1049\'
Last foler name varies regarding locale, I guess.
UML template is named 'DBUML_M.VSTX'

Answer (score 1):

I think because it's Standard's ver.

I don't know if you write your code in VS.
But if you did, just go to ARCHITECTURE - new Diagram.
& choose yours, & the VS 'll take the care of the rest  :)

Comment: Architecture projects / UML diagramming in Visual Studio is available only for Ultimate Editions. So, if you do not have Visual Studio Ultimate, you wont be able to create UML diagram from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for UML sequence diagrams, try searching for UML Sequence in the search box and add them.

- Search for UML Sequence in the search box -> Select all shapes and add to My shapes (user defined name).

You can either browse through My shapes to access them. They will be available in the in the sidebar nevertheless once you search.